# Contracting a solid torus to mobius band

Tags: homotopy-theory, mobius-band

A mobius band can be obtained from a solid torus by strong deformation retraction.

Visually the mobius band is obtained by continuously rotating the diameter in the disk around the torus.

If I write out the explicit parametrizations of the torus and mobius band, what is the map that gives the deformation?

Comment: That depends a _lot_ on which explicit parametrizations of the torus and mobius band we write out.

Comment: If you write your parameterisation so that the Möbius band is embedded in the torus with the boundary of the band intersecting the boundary of the torus, you can use a normal projection onto the Möbius band from the torus. In your case, it would be the projection of the disk onto the diameter.